# ACE Editor - enableLiveAutoCompletion - Disable Auto Select

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I have enableLiveAutoCompletion set to True which works great, except that our users do not want the first word to be automatically selected. For example, if the last word in a line of code is "x" and the user hits enter the first auto complete suggestion for the word x is auto filled.

[image: autocomplete]

Is there any way to disable the automatic selection of the first word suggestion on enter and force the user to use arrow keys? Or perhaps is there a way I add a blank keyword to the keyword list that is always matched by the completer function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in [language_tools.js#L166](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.4.14/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L166) not resetting the value set from [autocomplete.js#L496](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.4.14/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L496)

the following hack seems to work around it

```
if (editor.completer) delete editor.completer.autoSelect
var Autocomplete = ace.require("ace/autocomplete").Autocomplete;
Autocomplete.prototype.__defineSetter__("autoSelect", function() { })
Autocomplete.prototype.__defineGetter__("autoSelect", function() { })
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The workaround you suggested worked for me.